# Element-wise weave of two arrays used with numpy repeat

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

I have two arrays of unequal length *val1* and *val2* that I am trying to weave together in a specific way that is defined by the equal-length arrays *mult1* and *mult2*. In general, my arrays are very long (~1e6 elements), and this is a performance-critical bottleneck in my calculation, so I cannot afford to do a python-for loop and so I am trying to take advantage of vectorized functions in Numpy. For the sake of being explicit:

```
mult1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0])
mult2 = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])

val1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
val2 = np.array([-1, -2, -3])

desired_final_result = np.array([-1, 1, 2, 3, -2, 4, -3])
```

The weaving of *val1* and *val2* is defined by the following element-wise procession through the indices of *mult1* and *mult2*. Each entry of the two *mult* arrays defines how many elements to choose from the corresponding *val* array. We proceed element-wise through the *mult* arrays; the value of *mult1[i]* determines how many entries we choose from *val1*, then we proceed to the value of *mult2[i]* to select the appropriate number of *val2* entries, always choosing the *val1* entries to come first for each index i.

Note that **len(val1) = mult1.sum()** and **len(val2) = mult2.sum()**, so we always end up with a final array with **len(desired_final_result) = len(val1) + len(val2)**.

### Explicit explanation of minimal example

- Since entry *i=0* of *mult1* is **0**, we select **0** entries from *val1* and move on to entry *i=0* of *mult2*, which is **1**, so we select **1** entry from *val2*. This explains why the first entry of desired_final_result is -1.
- Since entry *i=1* of *mult1* is **1**, we select **1** entry from *val1* and move on to entry *i=1* of *mult2*, which is **0**, so select **0** entries from *val2*.  This explains why the second entry of desired_final_result is 1.
- Since entry *i=2* of *mult1* is **2**, we select the next **2** entries from *val1* and move on to entry *i=2* of *mult2*, which is **1**, so we select the next **1** entry from *val2*.  This explains why entries 2-4 of desired_final_result are 2, 3, -2.
- Since entry *i=3* of *mult1* is **1**, we select the next **1** entry from *val1* and move on to entry *i=3* of *mult2*, which is also **1**, so we select the next **1** entry from *val2*.  This explains why entries 5-6 of desired_final_result are 4, -3.
- Finally, since the *i=4* of both *mult1* and *mult2* is **0**, we have nothing left to do and our array is filled.

### Question

Is there a way to use vectorized functions such as *np.repeat* and/or *np.choose* to solve my problem? Or do I need to resort to coding this calculation up in C and wrapping it into python?

Comment: Cython or Numba would let you write a straightforward loop for this and have it be quick.

Comment: Due to your slices and input being of varying length, I also find it unlikely that it can be reasonably vectorized.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear that the length of the two *mult* arrays will always be equal.

Comment: OK, but `val1` and `val2` not, and the subarrays you want to tailor together especially not. I'm not saying that it must be impossible, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was.

Comment: Ahh, right. Ok, well if it's not possible then it's not possible. Like I said, I can always code it up "manually" in cython, but I find that I can never beat Numpy when there exists a natural solution that way, which is why I asked. Thanks for giving it some thought anyway, @AndrasDeak, I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has ideas before going that route.

Comment: https://memegenerator.net/instance/30938524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a Boolean index into the result array:

```
mult = np.array([mult1, mult2]).ravel('F')
tftf = np.tile([True, False], len(mult1))
mask = np.repeat(tftf, mult)

result = np.empty(len(val1) + len(val2), int)
result[ mask] = val1
result[~mask] = val2
```

Edit - I believe this works too:

```
idx = np.repeat(mult1.cumsum(), mult2)
result = np.insert(val1, idx, val2)
```

It's short, but it may not be faster.

Comment: Oh, huh. You can just build a mask array with the `repeat` call and use that to place elements directly. That's much simpler than what I did.

Comment: Wow, that's really beautiful @morningsun. You've actually showed me this np.tile trick before, but I didn't realize how useful it was until now. Brilliant!

Comment: I should also add that I went ahead and coded up the "brute force" method in cython. Even after cleaning my cython very thoroughly of any python layer, I find that for a ~1e6-length array, your solution is about ~2.5x faster than mine. Bravo.

Comment: @user2357112 - I think if one wants to generalize to more than 2 arrays you'll end up with an array of labels, similar to your answer.

Comment: @morningsun - second solution is 1. more slick, 2. less intuitive (to me anyway), 3. about 30% slower for large arrays with order unity multiplicity. So, bonus points for numpy wizardry, but I think your first solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with NumPy routines, but the best I've come up with is pretty clumsy:

```
reps = numpy.empty([len(mult1)*2], dtype=int)
reps[::2] = mult1
reps[1::2] = mult2

to_repeat = numpy.empty_like(reps)
to_repeat[::2] = -1   # Avoid using 0 and 1 in case either of val1 or val2 is empty
to_repeat[1::2] = -2

indices = numpy.repeat(to_repeat, reps)
indices[indices==-1] = numpy.arange(len(val1))
indices[indices==-2] = numpy.arange(len(val1), len(val1) + len(val2))

final_result = numpy.concatenate([val1, val2])[indices]
```